# How to protect my .NET EXE from de4dot

Tags: .net, obfuscation

There is this program called de4dot which basically reverse obfuscates almost any assembly, such as .NET reactor protected assemblies, etc. Is there really an effective method of protecting your .NET code?

Comment: Note to moderators: this is not a duplicate question. The proposed duplicate has nothing to do with de4dot. It did not even mentioned there.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a dupe, de4dot is not just any simple reflector, it is a **deobfuscator** that reflects obfuscated code.